# Use Rollup to bundle the application plus Run the App locally for development

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rollupjs

I want to bundle my React application using Rollup.

I also want to run the application on a server for local development from a folder called "test".

Thats where the React application is initiated.

folder structure (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oo3TY.png)

My rollup.config.mjs

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import serve from 'rollup-plugin-serve'
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload'
import html from '@rollup/plugin-html'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser'
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external'
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace'

import packageJson from './package.json' assert { type: 'json' }

export default [
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: 'cjs',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: 'esm',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      resolve(),
      replace({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
      }),
      commonjs(),
      html(),
      serve({
        open: true,
        verbose: true,
        contentBase: 'dist/esm',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3000,
      }),
      livereload({ watch: 'dist/esm' }),
      typescript({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.json' }),
      postcss(),
      terser(),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: 'dist/esm/types/index.d.ts',
    output: [{ file: 'dist/index.d.ts', format: 'esm' }],
    plugins: [dts()],
    external: [/\.s?css$/],
  },
]
```

I'm getting the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6sfu.png)

My question is: How do I serve the React application on localhost:3000 from the folder "test"?

I've tried using different paths in the ContentBase option in the serve module.